# Scaling SpringBoot Rest-API

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-swarm

I'm currently creating a Spring Boot Rest-API.
Part of this API is scheduled and runs every few seconds. Also the Processing of these is very resource intensive, and everything runs as parallel as possible.
As first my approach I have thougth of was that, due to the resource intensity, every customer get's his own sever. The downside of this is that everytime a new customer wants to use my software i need to rent a new server. And the Software is not realy a SaaS anymore.

Now I thought about it for some time and thought about scaling the whole thing and adding a workload management which automatically forwards scheduled tasks to a worker. After a little research I came up with Docker Swarm.
Now I have the question if something like this can be implemented with Docker Swarm.

Comment: Docker swarm is deprecated and should not be used. Look at kubernetes instead.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer But this is something I can obtain with kubernetes?

Comment: Why are trying to create new server for every new customer..? Instead of try multi tenant architecture.

Comment: @Nimal -- Yes, a lot easier than with Swarm and with a lot more support.

Comment: @GnanaJeyam I have Tenants in the main backend. But my problem was, that when a added the Task scheduling part (1.Task runs every 20s, 2. every 10 minutes and more) for multiple users, that for the task that runs every 20s for mulitple users it doesn't work in parallel so the task runs for user 1 process x-items and then for user 2 it processes x items and then for user 1 then rest. But I need it full in parallel So that the different users do not get in each other's way.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer Say I schedule a task ever 30 seconds and this for all my for example 20 customers. This task makes a rest request to another serverice. Now how do I do the workbalance for the returend answers of the 20 responses. So that every response get process without getting interupt by an other response. Because i cant get fully parallelism this is the reason why I came up with docker swarm or with kubernetes

Comment: Yes, you can do this with kubernetes. Though, what you're describing is a pretty poor way of thinking about it and doesn't really lend itself to good modelling. You'd be better of thinking about response-times and latencies, rather than the model you currently have. Either way, swarm doesn't exist any more and kubernetes is the modern way to build distributed systems.

Comment: One last thing -- spring boot is the wrong thing to do with these requirements. You should be using nodejs, with kubernetes, not spring-boot.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer In what way is Spring boot the wrong thing? My problem is that I am not familiar with Nodejs or with the JS/TS corner.

Comment: Then use spring, but node lends itself more readily to a distributed architecture and is, usually, simpler and less code than the Java equivalent, and is usually much lighter.